# How can I compare a user sha-512 password with a database password to login a user?

Tags: php, mysql, security, password-protection

I have this hashed password with a random generated salt, and I'm trying to figure out how I can possibly compare a password entered into a login form with an existing crypt password. Here's the formula I'm using to enter the password when creating a user:

```
$salt = mt_rand();
$hashedPassword = crypt($password, '$6$rounds=5000$'.$salt);
```

How can I compare two hashed password (one from the database and one from the login form) to see if they match?

Comment: sha-512 is a hash function,  not an encryption algorithm.  What do you mean compare them?  its a string,  in php you just use `==`.  This question is baffling.

Comment: @Rook What I mean is that when a user is created, the password is hashed using crypt sha-512 with salt appended to it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php , and is then inserted into the database. When a user logs into the site, the password and username need to be verified. Obviously, you can't write a mysql query stating SELECT * FROM users WHERE hashedpassword = the_password_in_question, or can you? Do you not have to somehow rehash the password with the salt that the user submitted on the login form to compare it to the hashed password in the database?

Comment: @Scott - you are correct. Rook just misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know what the salt is for that particular user - so be sure you're saving the salt. Then just add the salt to the user entered password and encrypt that and compare those together.

Comment: Would it be counterproductive to store the salt in the database, right next to the username and password?

Comment: no its all right, you need to store it there. the salt should be long enough (I cant give a length here... it may be 2 to 200 characters) so someone who gets your database cant just run it with a rainbow table that contains all 50 password up to 50 characters - thats what the salt is for.

Comment: Additional note: you may consider adding another few characters to the salt in php (hardcoded, same characters for all password) - then even when the database is compromised a few characters are still missing. The chance of losing your php scripts and database at the same time is (a little) slimmer that just one of them

Comment: @swatkins thanks, I just want to make sure I understand this correctly. The user submits username and password to the authenticateUser() method. authenticateUser() gets the salt from the db where username = username. The salt is then added to the entered password. Another query is made to see if hashedPassword = hashedPassword and if it does, the user is authenticated. Does that seem like a good approach?

Comment: @Rook -1 crypt is not a form of encryption. I know this. Where you got the idea that I thought otherwise is what baffles me.

Comment: @Scott: Yes, that's pretty much it. On registration, you will create the random salt, concatenate that salt with the user's chosen password, then encrypt that. You will save the user's information (username, email, salt, encrypted password, etc.). -- When you need to authenticate the user, you will take the user's info (username, email, salt, encrypted password), and run the same encryption on the salt and password that the user entered in the login form - then compare the two encrypted strings. As Alex said, it's necessary to make the salt fairly long and use various character types.